# PHP IF statement returns true value only once in While Loop

Tags: php, mysql, insert-into

this is my first steps in PHP because I don't use it in my work. I would like to prepare form which will add data to database tables. 
I prepared this piece of code:

```
<?php 

require "init.php";

$marina_id=$_POST["marina_id"];
$b_cor=$_POST["b_cor"];
$size=$_POST["size"];
$available_place=$_POST["available_place"];
$l_cor=$_POST["l_cor"];
$is_open=$_POST["is_open"];
$description=$_POST["description"];

$sql= "insert into marinas (marina_id, b_cor, l_cor, size, available_place, is_open, description) values('$marina_id', '$b_cor', '$l_cor', '$size', '$available_place', '$is_open', '$description');";
if (mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{
  echo "values were added";
} else {
  echo "values were not added";
}
$count = 0;
while ($count<$size)
{
    if ($count<$available_place) {
        $isavailable = 1;
        $accesscode = "";
    } else {
        $isavailable = 0;
        $accesscode = "abcdefgh";
    }
    $dock_id=(string)$marina_id."0".(string)$count;
    $nullObject="";
    $sql2= "insert into places (
        place_id, 
        b_cor, l_cor, 
        is_available, 
        plan, 
        depth, 
        width, 
        length, 
        description, 
        marina_id, 
        access_code, 
        reserved_from, 
        reserved_to, 
        last_update) values (

        '$dock_id', 
        '$b_cor', 
        '$l_cor', 
        '$isavailable',
        '$nullObject', 
        '$nullObject', 
        '$nullObject', 
        '$nullObject', 
        '$nullObject', 
        '$marina_id', 
        '$accesscode', 
        '$nullObject',
        '$nullObject', 
        '$nullObject');";
    if (mysqli_query($con, $sql2)) //$con comes from init.php
    {
    echo "complete.";
    } else {
    echo "something wrong with data.";
    }
    $count = $count+1;
}


 ?>
```

My idea was to insert a row with data into marinas table and based on its "size" value add extra rows with data to places table as many times as size value is. I used while loop, but my IF statement for $sql2 returns true only once and I don't have any idea why is that. For me, code logic seems ok and some data was added. Is there any limitation in PHP for the solution like mine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if place_id is a autoincrement key. Maybe it could be false because it violates the uniqueness of the key.

Comment: If this is true, then why *$dock_id=(string)$marina_id."0".(string)$count;* doesn't make place_id  value unique? Is it not correct way to connect integer value with string?

Comment: Another way is to encapsulate the integer in quotes:

$foo = 5;
$foo = "$foo"

put echo to print the query

Comment: Thank you so much Francesco. As you said, there was a problem with unique key. I made mistake during DB configuration and set 'unique' for marina_id instead of place_id.